# How to show custom page when user hit the website

Tags: php

Scenario: Our PHP website e.g "https://test.testcompany.com" will change to some other URL that is not decided. So I want to display my custom Html page e.g information.html. when the user hit our site.
How we can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it the `DirectoryIndex` (if you’re on Apache) …?

Comment: No, We are not on Apache.

Comment: Do you want us to keep guessing, or do you think it might perhaps be a bit more clever if you _told_ us then at this point, what your actual setup is …? Please go read [ask].

Comment: Redirect from your current index page? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php Or load the file from your current index page and show its contents? It might help if you stated _which_ server you are using or maybe adapt @04FS' comment to your current server software, I'm pretty sure every server software has a way to set the "DirectoryIndex"

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect whatever you want by using htaccess

OR

you can achieve by adding script :

```
window.location = "http://example.com";
```

Comment: Sorry, "_No, We are not on Apache._"